# Tool to check Microsoft Patch release dates

Tags: windows-server-2008

Our production window to apply any patches is always the 3rd weekend of the month. So in May-14 it would be the weekend of 05/17 and 05/18.
Since Microsoft releases the patches always on 2nd Tuesday of every month which is 05/08. Our infrastructure team takes a week to analyse and gives us  a go ahead to apply these patches in UAT instance that will be 05/17. This will give us only couple of days to test this in UAT and apply the same weekend into PROD. This timeline is really short to test and apply this into Production.

Requirement -->Any application/tool where we can see the patch release dates which will help us to select patches released a month back or so. This way we get a month to test the latest patches in UAT and then apply it in PROD the next month.

Is this something any one have encountered or have done it before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WSUS targeting (whether System Center Configuration Manager integrated or not) to control the rollouts. Make computer groups for UAT, Development, Testing, Staging, and Production... or whatever your IT shop wants your rollout groups to be. Don't roll out to production until your previous rollout groups are tested stable with the new patches. Don't do things on the 3rd weekend of the month just because that's the way it's always been done. Patch when you're ready - When your previous rollout groups have been tested.

If you have another CMDB/Service Desk system other than System Center, then apply the same advice to that.

The WSUS console does list "release date" for the various patches that it has downloaded.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Can I deploy a particular month's update to the systems? Let's suppose I want Windows updates that were released in February and the preceding months only to be applied (just as an assumption). Is it doable?

Comment: Yes, you can manually control exactly which patches you wish to install and which you don't. You "Approve" the updates with WSUS, and then clients will download them via Windows Update (but the 'Windows Update' server will actually be your on-premises WSUS server.) As an alternative to manual administration, there are also a lot of resources (such as Powershell scripting resources) for automatically controlling WSUS. Just one example: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/01/21/introduction-to-poshwsus-a-free-powershell-module-to-manage-wsus.aspx